# Meaning and usage of 単位

Tags: meaning, words

I know [単位](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%8D%98%E4%BD%8D) can indicate unit of measurement, but I can't really understand what does it adds, and if it's needed or something extra; I also tried on [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%8D%98%E4%BD%8D), but while I understand the definition, I don't really understand its usage.

Here's an example; as context, an alien is approaching the spaceship, and the commander asks about its distance; the answer is:

> あと9000キロ単位です

What I don't understand is: would the sentence be grammatical also without 単位, like "あと9000キロです"? If yes, what does it add? If not, is there any case in which removing it is right? I think for example about the title "いつだって僕らの恋は10センチだった".

Comment: Well, what little context you gave sounds like part of a work of science fiction. It seems to me キロ単位 is used instead of キロ because together as a compound it is a fictional unit of measurement. Usually when you say Aキロ単位, you mean everything is calculated based on Aキロ or by the Aキロ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This website](https://anime-diary.net/sidonia/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%89%E3%83%8B%E3%82%A2%E3%81%AE%E9%A8%8E%E5%A3%AB%E3%81%AE%E3%80%8C%E5%8D%98%E4%BD%8D%E3%80%8D.html) says a manga uses キロ単位 in the literal sense: 1000 x unit length, where there is no indication of what the unit length is. In this particular manga, キロ単位 seems different from *km*. So 9000キロです is of course grammatical, but would mean the usual 9000km.

I don't think it is common to use キロ this way. (I knew the manga, but never really thought what exactly it meant.)

---

In terms of ordinary usage, 1キロ単位 would be used like 1キロ単位で売る=*sell by the kilo* (that is, it is not possible to buy 1500g for example).

Another usage which is kind of similar is 単位当たり=*per unit*. This 単位 means a unit, which can be different depending on the context.